# Can I prevent a tabs from switching tab?

Tags: codenameone

I have a `tabs` for a wizard process.

Is it possible to achieve that if certain conditions are not met, avoid proceeding to the next step (avoid switching to the next tab)?

Could I achieve my requirement in the `SelectionListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectionListener` is problematic as it's a little too late and doesn't provide us with an object we can use.

First disable the swipe action by using `setSwipeActivated(false);`.
Swiping is a bit problematic to block as it provides a preview of the next tab.

You can override `setSelectedIndex(int, boolean)` to return in such a case. Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
private void enableTabs(Tabs t, boolean enable) {
     for(Component c : t.getTabsContainer()) {
         c.setEnabled(enable);
     }
}
```

Then use `enableTabs(t, false)` to disable all the tabs and use `true` later to re-enable them.